# OpenSAML Is Not Working

Tags: opensaml, fips

I am using the OpenSAML Java library to process the SAML token that comes from an IDP. The OpenSAML library is using a dependent library bcprov-jdk15xxx.jar which is non FIPS compliant. My requirement is to use FIPS compliant libraries in my application. Is there a way to make OpenSAML FIPS compliant? I found one bc-fips-1.0.0.jar, but its not working.

Thanks, Mounika

Comment: Hi @MPK are you able to find the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can register any JCE provider, like bouncy castle and OpenSAML will use it. Also give a higher priority to JCE lib. Can you provide the sample code you are using?